# excel spreadsheet referencing an activex control

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2013. I have added an activex control to my spreadsheet. The control is a checkbox which I have named chkAD1. My spreadsheet is called "timeseries_AD".

I am trying to reference the checkbox to check its value however without any joy. I have tried the lines below,

```
 worksheets("timeseries_AD").OleObjects("chkAD1").Value
```

This results in the error message "unable to get the OLEObjects property of the worksheet class".

I have read that an activex control has two names. One is the name of the shape that contains the control the other is the code name. I'm not sure which one I have changed. I clicked on my control and in the Name Box renamed it to "chkAD1". Is that the shape name or code name I have changed?

**UPDATE - Apologies**

Sorry the control I added is not an activex control it is actually a form control.

Comment: go to the sheet with the checkbox. get in design mode (button next to insert button) and then in design mode double click the checkbox.

Comment: What does `Msgbox worksheets("timeseries_AD").Shapes("chkAD1").Name` return? An error?

Comment: @Goosebumbs I'm in design mode and double clicking on the control doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Rory that line returns me the name i.e. "chkAD1"

Comment: make sure you select the checkbox before you double click it

Comment: @Goosebumbs nothing still appears to happen. I can see the outline of the control with the 6 squares to resize it I then double click on it nothing happens

Comment: that is strange. for me (also in excel 2013) it opens the `private sub checkbox_click()` like in a userform. have you tried what I answered below?

Comment: I have already assigned the checkbox to a macro. I would like to know the value of the checkbox i.e. is it either true or false though

Comment: I read somewhere you can just do `CheckBox1.Value` . So I suggest you try to do that on the original name of the checkbox (not 'chkAD1')

Comment: I tested that and it worked, look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me.
When I check the box I get a messagebox that says TRUE.
And when I uncheck it I get a messagebox that says FALSE

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    MsgBox CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```